# Why does this not converge uniformly? (fourier series)

Tags: fourier-series, uniform-convergence

Given the function
$$f(x) =\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if } -\pi \leq x \leq 0,\\    1, & \text{if } 0 < x \leq \pi.
\end{cases}$$
The fourier series for this is
$$Sf(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (2k-1)x}{2k-1}.$$
It asks me does $Sf(x)$ converge uniformly for $-\pi \leq x \leq \pi$. It says it doesn't, but I'm not sure of a quick way to do this. I also am not sure if I can use the definition either, as it'll still give me a series starting at $k=n+1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin (2k-1)x}{2k-1}$ is a sequence of continuous functions. If it converges uniformly then the limit is continuous, impossible since $f_n$ converges (almost everywhere) to $f$  which is discontinuous at $x=0$

Comment: Ah I see. So it's basically the contrapositive of your first two sentences, (which says either at least one of $f_n$ is discontinuous, or the convergence is not uniform (and we know $f_n$ is continuous as it's made up of continuous functions))?

Comment: You should work on the proof that $f$ is equal to its Fourier series, at least when $f$ is $C^1$. This works by writing $f_n = f \ast D_n$ where $D_n$ is the [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel)